# getting the value of a cell from another sheet with a fixed column and a variable row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple google appscript where I need to get the value of one cell from another google sheet. The cell always has the same column ("A"), but the row will vary depending on the number passed to the script. I have tried using IMPORTRANGE and INDIRECT with string variables but I always get a parse error or a NAME? error or some type of syntax error when I run it.

Would someone kindly help educate me on the proper way to specify the setFormula?

Specifically I am trying to get the following line of appscript to work in a function where instead of hardcoding the row 7, i have a variable for the row number (i have "xxx" in the url for confidentiality purposes):

spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxx","Videos!A7")');

I have tried several iterations including:

```
var sheetname = "Videos!A";
var row = "7";
var filenameRange = sheetname.toString()+row.toString();
```

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxx","Videos!Arow")');

spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxx","Videos!A"&row)');

spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxx",INDIRECT("A"&row.tostring())');
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64401370/edit) your question to show the script you tried. Also be more specific. Do you want to set a formula using google apps script? Then tell us which exactly formula you want to add and which are the variables in this formula. Help `us` to help `you`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are on the right track, you just need to [concatenate](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat) the static string with the dynamic variable

For this, replace

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxx","Videos!Arow")');`

with

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxx","Videos!A' + row + '")');`

Basically, if you use single quotes `'` for delimiting the formula string, you need to separate the static string from the variable by

- closing the single quotes `'`
- concatenate with `+`
- Opening the singles quotes `'` and continue with the rest of the static string